# Question on the coskeleton functor $\mathbf{coskel}'$ for pointed simplicial sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

There is an abstract  [construction of the coskeleton functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+skeleton) for simplicial set as follows:

Fix an integer $n\geq 0$ and take the inclusion of the full subcategory $i_n\colon\Delta_{\leq n}\hookrightarrow \Delta$. The induced functor
$$
i_{n*}\colon sSet\to sSet_{\leq n}
$$
given by $X\mapsto X\circ i_n$ has a right-adjoint $i_n^!\colon sSet_{\leq n}\to sSet$ and the composition $\mathbf{coskel}_n=i_n^!\circ i_{n*}$ is the *$n$-coskeleton functor* and it comes with a natural map $X\to \mathbf{coskel}_n(X)$.

I want to do the same for the pointed situation: Let $n\geq 0$ be an integer and cosinder the functor
$$
i'_{n*}\colon sSet_*\to sSet_{*\leq n}
$$
given by $X\mapsto X\circ i_n$ for a pointed simplicial set $X\in sSet_*=*\downarrow sSet\cong\operatorname{Fun}(\Delta^{op},Set_*)$.
This has a right-adjoint ${i_n'}^{!}\colon sSet_{*\leq n}\to sSet_*$. Let the composition $\mathbf{coskel'}_n={i_n'}^{!}\circ i_{n*}'$ be the *pointed $n$-coskeleton functor*. It comes with a natural map $X\to \mathbf{coskel}'_n(X)$.

> Is $X\to \mathbf{coskel}'_n(X)$ for a pointed simplicial set $X\in sSet_*$ an isomorphism on the simplicial homotopy group $\pi_i(-):=[\Delta^i/\partial\Delta^i, -]_{pointed}$ for $0\leq i<n$ and is $\pi_i(\mathbf{coskel}'_n(X))=0$ for $i\geq n$?

For the unpointed situation this seem to be true as stated [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+skeleton#Truncation) where an isomorphism of the simplicial homotopy groups mean *an isomorphism with respect to all basepoints*. The question is thus probably easy to answer but I am unsure if there is a picky basepoint-detail going wrong in the pointed case. Thank you.

Comment: Your notations are inverted: the functor $- \circ i_n$ is typically denoted by $i_n^*$, not $(i_n)_*$ (because postcomposition is contravariant), whereas its right adjoint is often denoted $(i_n)_!$ (because now it's covariant).

Answer (score 0):

The pointed question reduces to the unpointed one in the obvious way.

I will change notation to better align with what I'm more familiar with. I will also suppress the $n$ subscripts. In particular:

- $i^*$ denotes the pullback functor $\mathrm{sSet} \to \mathrm{sSet}_{\leq n} : X \mapsto X \circ i$
- $i_*$ denotes the right adjoint of $i^*$
- $i_!$ denotes the left adjoint of $i^*$

and I will use primes to indicate the corresponding functors on pointed objects.

A pointed object in a category $\mathcal{C}$ with a terminal object can expressed as a functor $\mathbf{2} \to \mathcal{C}$ (where $\mathbf{2}$ is the category $0 \to 1$ with one arrow) with the additional property that $0$ is mapped to a terminal object. Write the category of such functors as $\mathrm{Fun}^L(\mathbf{2}, \mathcal{C})$.

Since right adjoints preserve all limits, and in particular preserve terminal objects, the adjunction $i^* \dashv i_*$ induces on the functor categories by precomposition restricts to an adjunction $i^{*'} \dashv i_*'$
between $ \mathrm{Fun}^L(\mathbf{2}, \mathrm{sSet}) $ and $\mathrm{Fun}^L(\mathbf{2}, \mathrm{sSet}_{\leq n}) $.

($i_!$ also sends the terminal object to the terminal object, so you get $i_!' \vdash i^{*'}$ too)

In particular this means $\mathbf{coskel}'$ is computed by applying $\mathbf{coskel}$; in particular, $\mathbf{coskel}'(X,x) = (\mathbf{coskel}(X), \mathbf{coskel}(x))$, and thus

$$ \pi_i (\mathbf{coskel}'(X,x)) \cong \pi_i(\mathbf{coskel}(X), \mathbf{coskel}(x)) $$